# Custom line breaks in biblatex bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I'm using `biblatex` with `bibstyle=authoryear` option. I'd like to customize the style to insert a line break after the year in each bibliography entry.  Currently, an entry looks like this

[image: authoryear bibliography entry]

I'd like to have a line break after `(1993).` so that `First Draft of a...` started on the new line.

Is there a user-side biblatex customization option or a command to accomplish this?

There's an option to have a line break after each block in the entry `block=par`, and it looks like this

[image]

However this is not what I need.  I want the line break to be after the Author-Year line, and the rest of the blocks to be in one paragraph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution is to redefine the `\labelnamepunct` command. This command is executed after the name and title are printed by biblatex drivers  in the `authoryear` style. A possible re-definition is

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\newunitpunct\par}
```

This produce the following output

[image]

Comment: How can I adjust this to have a new line directly after the author names (i.e. so that the first line only includes authors names and the second line includes the date)? I don't want any punctuation after the author names.

Comment: @roland the `authoryear` style puts the date in the `author` `editor` and `translator` bibmacros. So, you have to modify those. The simplest way is to use the `xpatch` package, and `\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}
  {\newline\usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}
  {}
  {}`

Comment: @Guido this moved the date to the next line, but it also moved the comma. So the second line starts as ", 1990." How can I remove both the comma (and space) before the date and the dot after the date? I want a tabspace after the date without any punctuation.

Comment: @roland what style are you using? Probably you should post a new question  with a complete MWE.  For removing the dot after `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space}`

Comment: @Guido I am using ``authoryear``  . Everything you have told me has worked well except that the second line starts with a comma and then the date like ``, 1990``.

Comment: @roland plain `authoryear` produces "Last, First (year). title", you have "author, year". So there must be something extra.

Comment: So sorry about that my mistake! I had added a comma earlier. I got it now! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using the `xpatch` package. You'll  to make the modification for every entry driver — at least for every entry you use. I also replace the quotes around title with colour:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article} % this must go first, there are many different classes
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Neu93,
  author = {John von Neumann},
  title = {First Draft of a Report on the EDVAC},
  journaltitle = {IEEE Ann. Hist. Comput. },
  date = {1993},
  volume = {15},
  number = {4},
  pages = {27--75},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex)
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  }
  {%
  \newline\newblock
  }{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\color{VioletRed4!90!}#1\isdot}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have to repeat the patch for every driver.

Comment: Thanks, Guido. Yes, I meant to add this point, then forgot… I'll correct this at once.