# biblatex add line breaks after author and title

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex+biber and want to achieve that after the authors are printed a new line should begin, then the title should be printed and again a new line should start, where the rest is printed as usual. This [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191173/custom-line-breaks-in-biblatex-bibliography-entries) comes close to my problem, however I use the default style and the title is still not on a separate line.

Here is an example

```
Author1, Author2, and Author3. Title. In: Proceedings. Ed. John Doe. World. 2017
```

and how it should look like

```
Author1, Author2, and Author3.
Title.
In: Proceedings. Ed. John Doe. World. 2017
```

Below is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{inProc,
  author    = {Author11 and Author12 and Author13},
  editor    = {Editor1},
  title     = {Title1},
  booktitle = {Booktitle1},
  year      = {2017},
  pages     = {50--67},
  publisher = {Publisher1}
}
@article{article,
  author  = {Author21 and Author22},
  title   = {Title2},
  journal = {Journal2},
  year    = {2007},
  volume  = {29},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {29:1--29:27}
}
@book{book,
  author    = {Author31},
  title     = {Title3},
  year      = {1970},
  publisher = {Publisher3}
}
@incollection{inCollection,
   author    = {Author4},
   title     = {Title4},
   booktitle = {Booktitle4},
   pages     = {843--993},
   editor    = {Editor4},
   chapter   = {15},
   volume    = {B},
   series    = {Series4},
   publisher = {Publisher4},
   year      = {1990}
}
@techreport{techreport,
  author      = {Author5},
  institution = {Institution5},
  number      = {Number5},
  pages       = {Pages5},
  title       = {Title5},
  year        = {5}
}
@phdthesis{phdthesis,
  author    = {Author6},
  title     = {Title6},
  school    = {School6},
  month     = {Month6},
  publisher = {Publisher6},
  address   = {Address6},
  year      = {6}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first step is

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\newline\bibsentence}
```

to get a new line after the names.

Then you need something to jump to a new line after the title. Unfortunately, there is no standard delimiter to redefine here. The easiest way that worked for all entry types was the following

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\do#1{
  \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
    {\xpatchbibdriver{#1}
       {\printlist{language}%
        \newunit\newblock}
       {\printlist{language}%
        \printunit{\newline\bibsentence}}
       {}{}}
    {}} 
\abx@doentrytypes
\makeatother
```

This adds a newline after the language, which in all standard drivers comes right after the title. We use the `xpatch` package to change the bibliography drivers and apply the change to all drivers with a loop (`\abx@doentrytypes` is an internal macro that loops over all).

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\newline\bibsentence}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\do#1{
  \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
    {\xpatchbibdriver{#1}
       {\printlist{language}%
        \newunit\newblock}
       {\printlist{language}%
        \printunit{\newline\bibsentence}}
       {}{}}
    {}} 
\abx@doentrytypes
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{inProc,
  author    = {Author11 and Author12 and Author13},
  editor    = {Editor1},
  title     = {Title1},
  booktitle = {Booktitle1},
  year      = {2017},
  pages     = {50--67},
  publisher = {Publisher1}
}
@article{article,
  author  = {Author21 and Author22},
  title   = {Title2},
  journal = {Journal2},
  year    = {2007},
  volume  = {29},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {29:1--29:27}
}
@book{book,
  author    = {Author31},
  title     = {Title3},
  year      = {1970},
  publisher = {Publisher3}
}
@incollection{inCollection,
   author    = {Author4},
   title     = {Title4},
   booktitle = {Booktitle4},
   pages     = {843--993},
   editor    = {Editor4},
   chapter   = {15},
   volume    = {B},
   series    = {Series4},
   publisher = {Publisher4},
   year      = {1990}
}
@techreport{techreport,
  author      = {Author5},
  institution = {Institution5},
  number      = {Number5},
  pages       = {Pages5},
  title       = {Title5},
  year        = {5}
}
@phdthesis{phdthesis,
  author    = {Author6},
  title     = {Title6},
  school    = {School6},
  month     = {6},
  publisher = {Publisher6},
  address   = {Address6},
  year      = {6}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

An alternative solution to a loose bibliography like this with `block=par` is discussed in [Bibliography style for BibLaTeX similar to BibTeX+Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505148/35864).

Comment: That works perfectly fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The following solution will only give the desired result, if all the entries have the "In:", e.g. for articles without a journal, there won't be a new line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Neu93,
  author = {John von Neumann},
  title = {First Draft of a Report on the EDVAC},
  journaltitle = {IEEE Ann. Hist. Comput. },
  date = {1993},
  volume = {15},
  number = {4},
  pages = {27--75},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\newunitpunct\par}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\newline In:}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, I should have mentioned that I also have books and articles and so on. I will update my question.

Comment: @MaxMaier If you are updating, please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)