# Bibliography style for BibLaTeX similar to BibTeX+Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I pretty much like how the bibliography is rendered via BibTeX+Beamer as demonstrated by the `Metropolis` beamer theme:

[image]

Does there exist some BibLaTeX style with a similar look and feel? In particular I like the separation/newline between author, title, and remaining parts.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking for a `biblatex` style that emulates this formatting, but for regular documents, not for `beamer`. Is that correct?

Comment: If so, I think this may be a duplicate: [biblatex: title and authors to be switched and followed by a line break instead of punctuation](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/226843)

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm interested in a BibLaTeX style for beamer. I will have a look at the link you mentioned. Maybe it works for beamer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the style elements of BibTeX bibliographies rendered in `beamer` presentations don't actually come from the style, but from clever modifications that `beamer` applies to the bibliography environment and some relevant commands. Similar modifications are applied when `biblatex` is loaded (for example you also get the icons instead of numbers by default in the bibliography list and certain elements of the reference have a different colour).

If you are just after more frequent new lines in the bibliography you can try the `biblatex` option `block=par`, which inserts line breaks after each 'block' of information in the bibliography entry. What exactly constitutes a block depends on the bibliography style and its driver definitions.

```
\documentclass[british]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, block=par, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,companion,westfahl:space}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography slide with more frequent line breaks.]

---

What constitutes a block is defined by the bibliography style in the drivers. The driver for `@article` in [`standard.bbx` (ll. 26-62)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/a56983c242cefe4e92e6c2a5b2a763729169fe1e/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L26-L62) looks like this

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

If you want to change the number of blocks you need to add or remove some `\newblock` instructions here. Unfortunately, this can only happen by copy-paste-and-modifictation of the entire driver or by patching with `xpatch` (though that could get a bit messy here).

A different strategy is discussed in [biblatex add line breaks after author and title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351397/35864).

Comment: The option `block=par` sounds really interesting. Is it possible to define what constitutes a block? I would like to have only three blocks namely for author/editor and title and remaining part. Otherwise, an entry becomes quite large.

Comment: @MaxMaier That is sort of hard-coded in the bibliography drivers. See for example [the standard driver for `@article` in `standard.bbx`, ll. 26-62](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/a56983c242cefe4e92e6c2a5b2a763729169fe1e/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L26-L62) each `\newblock` marks a new block. You could remove the `\nwblock`s in places where you don't want them.

Comment: @MaxMaier I also found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351397/35864, which is one of your own questions. Maybe you can use that again?

Comment: yes, I also thought about my old question. At least by that I get the result of the separate blocks. Though, the font face, quotes, etc. are still not the same. I was digging into `beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` where such things are defined. I might adapt that to fit my needs. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.