# Changing title page's text in Overleaf University template

Tags: overleaf, templates

I'm a beginner, and I have a LateX template from Overleaf for my university (Palacky University).

I cant find any part of code that could change how the title page looks and what is most important - what it says. Code is below.

[image: heres a picture]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

%%% PACKAGES %%%

\usepackage{polyglossia} \setdefaultlanguage{czech} % change to your language %\setotherlanguage{czech} % if you need a specific part written in another language

% hyphenation rules for specialized words

%\AtBeginDocument{ %\hyphenation{pho-ton quan-tum} %}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes} \usepackage[xetex]{graphicx}

% see biblatex documentation \usepackage[sorting=none,style=phys,backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex} \usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} \usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{titlesec} \usepackage{pdfpages} \usepackage{microtype} \usepackage{unicode-math}

% needed for a specific command changing bibliography formatting \usepackage{xpatch}

% !!! LOREM IPSUM for demo purposes, you can get rid of this \usepackage{lipsum}

% Libertinus fonts \usepackage{libertinus-otf}

% At the moment, STIX looks better than Libertinus Math, but that will hopefully change soon. % feel free to comment this out and try Libertinus Math \setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

% metadata for the PDF file \hypersetup{ pdfauthor={Whatever is my name}, pdftitle={whatever is my thesis}, pdfsubject={whatever is my school}, pdfkeywords={lasers, photons, and stuff} }


%%% BIBLIOGRAPHY %%%

\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

% you may put the publications you authored in a separate category \DeclareBibliographyCategory{MyArticles} \addtocategory{MyArticles}{Smith2017}

% force the order you want by referencing them all here using \nocite \nocite{Smith2017}

%%% BIBLATEX OPTIONS AND TWEAKS %%%

% Biblatex enables editing .bib entries and configuring everything in your LaTeX document

% get rid of the months \DeclareSourcemap{   \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
    }   } }

% declare special bibliography contexts with optional prefixes \DeclareRefcontext{myarticles}{labelprefix=A} \DeclareRefcontext{books}{labelprefix=B}

% change the typesetting of reference numbers in the bibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\hspace{10pt}}

% declare command \citenum that prints a plain reference number % can be used in a sentence

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenum}   {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{labelprefix}}}   {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{labelnumber}}}   {}   {}

% produce clickable URL links for theses \letbibmacro{ORIG-institution+location+date}{institution+location+date} \renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date} {\iffieldundef{url}         {\usebibmacro{ORIG-institution+location+date}}      {\href{\thefield{url}}{\usebibmacro{ORIG-institution+location+date}}} }

% small caps typesetting of author names \DeclareNameWrapperFormat{author}{\textsc{#1}}

% make the 'and' between the last two authors upright and not small caps % taken from biblatex.def and modified \DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{ \textup{   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%   \addspace\bibstring{and}\space   } }

% after the authors list, there is a colon and a newline \renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\newline}

% the newline between name and journal is tricky to add, because there is no command to redefine. % here is some black magic using the package xpatch % taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351397/biblatex-add-line-breaks-after-author-and-title \makeatletter \def\do#1{   \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@#1}
    {\xpatchbibdriver{#1}
       {\printlist{language}%
        \newunit\newblock}
       {\printlist{language}%
        \printunit{\addcomma\newline}}
       {}{}}
    {}} \abx@doentrytypes \makeatother

% make the font size smaller for bibliography \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}   % if you don't like titles in quotes, this gets rid of them

%\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inproceedings,patent,incollection]{title}{% %  \iftoggle{bbx:chaptertitle} %    {#1\isdot} %    {}% %}




%%% PAGE HEADERS AND FOOTERS %%%

% !!! the narrow margins are inner margins, while the wider margins are outer margins % odd-numbered pages  1,3,5,... right side >>>
__text____ % even-numbered pages 2,4,6,... left side  >>> ____text__ % see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_page_construction

% page layout and margins are left at default settings

\pagestyle{fancy}

% this is here only so LaTeX does not complain \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

% the aim here is to have section names in the headings on the inner side % the way I think this works is: % when evaluating the \section[shortName]{fullName} command in the text, there is a \sectionmark command inside. % calling \markboth like below changes the current heading to shortName % works the same for chapters, both commands are redefined to cover the cases where the chapter does not contain a section immediately % !!! asterisk commands and table of contents do not contain marks, so you need to do it manually (see the main text) \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\normalfont\sffamily\textsc{#1}}{}} \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\normalfont\sffamily\textsc{#1}}{}}

% remove page numbers from the footer and put it into the header (outer side) \fancyfoot{} \fancyhf[HLE,HRO]{\thepage}

% redefine plain style to be compatible with fancy (beginning of chapters) \fancypagestyle{plain}{ %   \fancyhf{} % remove everything   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} }


%%% MISCELLANEOUS %%%

% hyperlinks are highlighted using colored text instead of colored boxes % !!! switch off for printing unless you want the color in print

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!80!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black} }


% heading styles, sans serif

\def\headingStyle{\sffamily}

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\headingStyle} \titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingStyle} \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\headingStyle} \titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\huge\headingStyle}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge\headingStyle}

% in case you like prefixes to distinguish tables and figures from other numbered references

%\renewcommand{\thefigure}{F\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}} %\renewcommand{\thetable}{T\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Around line #222 you will find

```
% LaTeX is not an efficient tool for visual typesetting, so the title page is done in Inkscape
\includepdf{title_page.pdf}
```

The cover of the page you see was made in advance and included in the document.

You can easily  design this  cover with LaTeX. It is nice starting exercise to learn the basics.

See [many examples and code for title pages](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf)

Also in [Gallery — Title Page](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/title-page)

Pick the one you like,  add your contents and try to modify it to fit any requirement you might have.

Ask questions in this site if you need further help.